# Dpkg failed to install package, now fails to remove broken package

Tags: linux, uninstall

So I tried installing the dokuwiki package on my raspberry pi, however the package failed to install. Upon trying to remove the package dpkg also fails with the following error:

```
String found where operator expected at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Element/Noninteractive/Multiselect.pm line 2, at end of line
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Debconf::Element::Noninteractive::Multiselect" (perhaps you forgot to load "Debconf::Element::Noninteractive::Multiselect"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd.pm line 68, <GEN50> line 5.
(Reading database ... 132035 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dokuwiki (0.0.20140505.a+dfsg-4) ...
dpkg: error processing package dokuwiki (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dokuwiki
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I thought there may be the possibility of an error in the 'Multiselect.pm' file, so I took a look and found something very odd:

```
#!odsrisin= eris-wet Tems tsleTaasamreS(ocdeseth d.gnonsed"p!
Lipa")ag  De  on  :Eifmeod::isnileerthti 0::{
lt  el  t;  se  trort;trseg asthqw.gebChnfdVElueenod:Nisin0]ra
 iv  ;
  1
```

I can see why dpkg would have trouble executing this file. Even the first line telling which program should be used to run this file is all garbled. My guess is that this file has either been obfuscated in some way or maybe uses something other than UTF-* encoding. It could just be corrupted too, I guess.

Anybody have any thoughts on this, and perhaps how I can remove this broken package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm not sure what happened to the original file, but I simply replaced it with one running on another Debian system. However, that still did not allow me to remove the dokuwiki package.

I figured I'd look at the configuration scripts for dokuwiki in */var/lib/dpkg/info/* and i found the script that was giving the error: dokuwiki.postinst. Running that script without any arguments threw an error about an invalid operator, so I added the following snippet of code to the head of the file:

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    ./dokuwiki.postinst a
    return
fi
```

It simply checks if the script was called with any arguments and if not, it calls itself with a meaningless argument (just 'a') and then returns.

After that, I ran

> dpkg -r dokuwiki

and it uninstalled without issue.